# How to retry urlfetch.fetch a few more times in case of error?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, exception

Quite often GAE is not able to upload the file and I am getting the following error:

```
ApplicationError: 2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/base/python_runtime/python_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/webapp/__init__.py", line 636, in __call__
    handler.post(*groups)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/picasa2vkontakte/1.348093606241250361/picasa2vkontakte.py", line 109, in post
    headers=headers
  File "/base/python_runtime/python_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/urlfetch.py", line 260, in fetch
    return rpc.get_result()
  File "/base/python_runtime/python_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/apiproxy_stub_map.py", line 592, in get_result
    return self.__get_result_hook(self)
  File "/base/python_runtime/python_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/urlfetch.py", line 355, in _get_fetch_result
    raise DownloadError(str(err))
DownloadError: ApplicationError: 2
```

How should I perform retries in case of such error?

```
        try:
            result = urlfetch.fetch(url=self.request.get('upload_url'), 
                                    payload=''.join(data),
                                    method=urlfetch.POST,
                                    headers=headers
                                    )
        except DownloadError:
            # how to retry 2 more times?
        # and how to verify result here?
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you can, move this work into [the task queue](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/overview.html). When tasks fail, they retry automatically. If they continue to fail, the system gradually backs off retry frequency to as slow as once-per hour. This is an easy way to handle API requests to rate-limited services without implementing one-off retry logic.

If you really need to handle requests synchronously, something like this should work:

```
for i in range(3):
  try:
    result = urlfetch.fetch(...)
    # run success conditions here
    break
  except DownloadError:
    #logging.debug("urlfetch failed!")
    pass
```

You can also pass `deadline=10` to urlfetch.fetch to double the default timeout deadline.

Comment: Thanks, @Drew Sears. Would it be correct to verify `status_code`: `if result.status_code == 200: break`?

Comment: Shouldn't be necessary. If fetch returns a failure code (404, 500) an exception will be thrown and nothing else in the try block will run, including the break.